# How is "so" correctly translated into predicate logic?

Tags: logic, notation, predicate-logic, logic-translation

I have come across an exercise that asks to have “There is only one ball, so you need to have it” translated into predicate logic. Using the predicates $\text{Ball}(x)$ for $x$ is a ball and $\text{Have}(x, y)$ for $x$ must have $y$, I translated it this way:

$$\exists x((\text{Ball}(x) \land \forall y(\text{Ball}(y) \rightarrow (x = y))) \rightarrow \text{Have}(\text{you}, x))$$

The answer in the back, on the other hand, is:

$$\exists x(\text{Ball}(x) \land \forall y(\text{Ball}(y) \rightarrow (x = y)) \land \text{Have}(\text{you}, x))$$

I want to know whether I am wrong or not, and why. The exercise and answer can be found here
https://textbooks.open.tudelft.nl/textbooks/catalog/view/53/144/370-1, on page $51$ (exercise $8$) and page $189$ respectively.

Thank you.

Comment: This question is not really a mathematics question, because it requires some linguistic knowledge to parse the meaning of the given sentence before even trying to translate it into predicate logic.

Comment: My first thought was: Probably you need some form of causality logic to formalize the natural language semantics of "so"...

Comment: Some clarification is needed. Are we talking about some kind of game that requires the use of a single ball? Is it the case that if we have a ball, then we can then play this game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like neither translation.

Yours is certainly not right, since your statement would be rather vacuously true if there exists something that is not a ball: that something would make $Ball(x)$ False, hence the whole antecedent of the conditional false, and therefore the whole conditional true.

But the one offered by the book merely says: "There exists one ball *and* you need to have it" ... which really doesn't capture the 'so' part.  Indeed, the statement given is really an expression of an argument: [This], *therefore* [that]. And there is really no truth-functional connective or other nice way to logically represent a 'therefore' or 'so'.

Of course, what you *can* do is to represent this argument using two statements in predicate logic, and use the *mathematical* 'therefore' in between:

$\exists x (Ball(x) \land \forall y (Ball(y) \to x = y))$

$\therefore$  $\exists x (Ball(x) \land Have(you,x))$

Answer (score 1):

"$\phi \to \psi$" means "not $\phi$ or $\psi$. So your formula permits for the possibility where there is not exactly one (i.e. no or more than one) ball. But we need to have that there is one ball, and that you have it. Though there is more to the semantics of "so" than just that both sides are the case; it additionally carries the meaning of a causal connection, and this additional meaning can not be expressed solely by truth-functional operators.

Answer (score 1):

$$A(z), \text{ so }B(z)$$ has the same meaning as `A(z), therefore B(z)`: it first asserts that `A(z)` is true, then implicitly asserts that `B(z)` is a consequence of `A(z)`, and finally concludes that `B(z)` is true. Its complete predicate-logic formalisation is $$A(z)\;\land\; \Big(A(z)\to B(z)\Big)\;\land\; B(z),$$ where the final conjunct is a logical redundancy.

> “There is only one ball, **so** you need to have *it*”

This statement's final word refers to a specific ball, which was introduced in the first part of the statement. So: $$\exists x\big(\operatorname{Ball}(x) \land \forall y(\operatorname{Ball}(y) \rightarrow x = y)\big) \;\land\; \operatorname{Ball}(z) \\
\land\quad \Big(\exists x\big(\operatorname{Ball}(x) \land \forall y(\operatorname{Ball}(y) \rightarrow x = y)\big) \;\land\; \operatorname{Ball}(z)\Big)\to \operatorname{Have}(\operatorname{you}, z)\\
\land\quad \operatorname{Have}(\operatorname{you}, z).$$

> I translated it this way:
> $$\exists x((Ball(x) \land \forall y(Ball(y) \rightarrow (x = y))) \rightarrow Have(you, x))$$
> The answer in the back, on the other hand, is:
> $$\exists x(Ball(x) \land \forall y(Ball(y) \rightarrow (x = y)) \land Have(you, x))$$

The main issue with your formalisation is that it fails to assert that there *actually* is only one ball, while the book's formalisation is merely asserting “you have the only ball” and failing to capture the given statement's implicit conditional.